# How to impelement Arima time series forecasting using python with cassandra database?

Tags: python, data-science, arima

Hello Guys I have cassandra table for arima time series forecasting can you share some basic step how to implement it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific: is this about getting the historical data from Cassandra, or about the ARIMA algorithmics?

Comment: Yes i am looking  this about getting the historical data from Cassandra, or about the ARIMA algorithmics?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with Cassandra database.

Common practice in python is to use database clients from PIP packages. In this case, `cassandra-driver` is the package you need.

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html

Then the following page provides a working python example with Cassandra database queries:

https://techfossguru.com/apache-cassandra-python-step-step-guide-ubuntu-example/

```
# simple example without security
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

server_address = "localhost" # or where Cassandra is hosted
keyspace = "my_keyspace" # or whatever you select

cluster = Cluster(server_address)
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
session.execute('select * from mytable limit 100 where somecolumn > 10;')  # get 100 matching lines from mytable
cluster.shutdown()
```

For ARIMA, it's a pretty complex algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average

I suggest first figuring out what the algo does and then browsing for reference implementations.